# Div unnaligned with other content but still in the wrapper

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, border

Hello I am working on this shopify theme that i want to customize. I took the footer and copied them to be between the menu and the picture slider. I did not change anything in the css nor the html ( I just renamed the id's and classes that affected the footer and renamed them). But the borders of the div and possibly the div goes out of alignment and is a bit more wider than the rest of the content. Here is the code and the demo:

```
<div id="footer1"   >

  <div id="big-footer1" class="row">

    <div  class="desktop-4 tablet-2 mobile-3 alpha">

       <a href="/Shop/List/Gym_and_Fitness?cm_sp=homepage-_-fitnesst1-_-10-06-14" id="A_4"><img src="/mrporter/content/2014/home/100614/t1.jpg" alt="" id="IMG_5" /></a>
    <h2 id="H2_6">
           A SPORTING SUMMER:<br id="BR_7" />WHAT TO WEAR
    </h2>

    </div>

    <div class="desktop-4 tablet-2 mobile-3">


       <a href="/Shop/List/Gym_and_Fitness?cm_sp=homepage-_-fitnesst1-_-10-06-14" id="A_4"><img src="/mrporter/content/2014/home/100614/t1.jpg" alt="" id="IMG_5" />     </a>
                <h2 id="H2_6">
              A SPORTING SUMMER:<br id="BR_7" />WHAT TO WEAR
                    </h2>


    </div>       

    <div id="" class="desktop-4 tablet-2 mobile-3 omega">

       <a href="/Shop/List/Gym_and_Fitness?cm_sp=homepage-_-fitnesst1-_-10-06-14" id="A_4"><img src="/mrporter/content/2014/home/100614/t1.jpg" alt="" id="IMG_5" /></a>
    <h2 id="H2_6">
        A SPORTING SUMMER:<br id="BR_7" />WHAT TO WEAR
    </h2>
    </div>


  </div>
```

And here is the css:

```
#big-footer1 { 
border-left: 1px solid {{ settings.footer-top-border }}; 
border-right: 1px solid {{ settings.footer-top-border }};
margin-bottom: 0px; 
margin-top: 0px;
border-bottom: 0px solid {{ settings.footer-bottom-border }}; 

list-style-type: none; 
}

#big-footer1 .alpha { border-right: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }}; }
#big-footer1 .omega { border-left: 1px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }}; }






@media screen and (max-width: 740px) {
#big-footer1 .alpha { border-right: 0px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }}; }
#big-footer1 .omega { border-left: 0px solid {{ settings.dotted_color }}; }
}


#big-footer1 { color: {{ settings.footer-text-color }}; }
#big-footer1 a { color: {{ settings.footer-text-color }}; }



#big-footer1 > div { padding: 0 20px; min-height: 120px;}


#big-footer1 ul {
list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
line-height: 34px;
}

#big-footer1 ul li { display: inline-block; margin: 0 5px; }

#footer1 { background: {{ settings.footer-background }}; padding-bottom: 20px; text-align: center; }
```

Comment: You mentioned a demo but I don't see one?

Comment: its the footer1 divs that is between navigation and picture slider. I have putted left and right borders that are not aligned with the other content and sticks out a bit. Can you see it?

Comment: Yes I see it now thanks. Answer below with why it is wider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has a width set to over 100%, which is why it is not aligned properly. The line of code you are looking for is: `.gridlock .row .row 102.083%`, which according to my browser is on line 19 of `stylesheet.css`. This is affecting the width of `<div id="big-footer1" class="row">`

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing out the line of code. But this line is affecting other parts of the website and If I change anything wouldnt all of the stuff with class row change?

Comment: So you can clone all the css for row, rename it row1, and set it to row1, like you did with footer to footer1. Otherwise yes, it would affect it all.

Comment: THanks man this worked. I am a bit of a newb with the responsive stuff and I appologise that I took your time for such a stupid question. But I will know for next time so thanks a lot. ;)

Comment: Not a problem at all! We all started somewhere please don't apologize. Glad I could help! Cheers! :)